# Getting a document from Firestore results in "The method 'data' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: data())"

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Flutter and trying to get a document from a collection; there is no error in the code but, still, the document is not obtained.

I am trying to return a variable having `String` in the method `_onPressed()` but I'm stuck at that point.

```
 Future _onPressed() async{
    var msg;
    await db.collection('Messages').doc(widget.brew.id).get().then((value){
      print(value.data()['Message']);
      return value.data()['Message'];
    });
    msg =  msg.data()['Message'];
    return msg;
  }
```

Comment: Your error says everything: The method 'data' was called on null. -> that means VALUE is null, so you are trying to call the method data in something null. You should check if VALUE is not null before trying to do anything to it

Answer (score 2):

Wrong assignment done here. change the above code

```
Future _onPressed() async{
    var docSnap = await db.collection('Messages').doc(widget.brew.id).get();
    if (docSnap.exists) {
        print('Document data: ${documentSnapshot.data()}');
        return docSnap.data()['Message'];
    } else {
        print('Document does not exist on the database');
        return docSnap.data()['Message'];
    }

  }
```

In current snippet, `msg.data()` throws the err as the msg was null at that time.

Comment: Again same error even Message is not null

Comment: updated the code; actually, we have to check whether the document snapshot exist. I highly recommend you to read this doc - https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/